# How to change previous domain when directing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, cors

I have a site here A which has a link to another site (different domain) B.

The site i'm dealing with (B) uses a plugin (which I cannot change), and at one point it checks the previous domain property value of the referrer window or parent window (I forget), and this ends up crashing the JS code because the previous domain is different than the current domain. Throws a CORS related error.

I can however update the link it goes it (from A) to any page on B. Is there a way from B I can use that can force the previous domain to become the current domain? Some special way to refresh the page may be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short of redirecting it to a server-side component that allows CORS via headers, any page you direct to on the front end will result in the same CORS restriction.

However, something like node or php or any other server aspect, or something like [CORS anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/), would wrap it the response in a header that browsers like Chrome or Firefox wouldn't reject.  Though to be fair it's mostly Chrome that throws a fit currently.

Comment: I can do a redirect in IIS. What headers should I use.

Comment: This gives you a breakdown for a variety of servers: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: In general it would be this header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *